# Fabricate Mass Effect 3 File

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is it possible to "fabricate" a save for Mass Effect 3?

I lost my save file for Mass Effect 3 after a freak computer crash, and I want to create a save file up to the point where I used to be. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no tool that will allow you to create a save file for the middle of the game from scratch. A [save editor](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/) can theoretically be used to alter a new save to be similar to what you had, but I doubt you would be able to play the game to completion with such a save due to bugs. Let this be a lesson on the importance of backing up your data.

Comment: Cheers. I am pissed off...

Comment: @SpartanEngineer sorry to hear that, but look on the bright side - at least it's not ME2 you have to replay.

Comment: You can edit your save file partway through in ME2 using Gibbed (to add resources, for example, or unlock Legion for squad use from the start). If Gibbed for ME3 is at all similar, theoretically you could do the same thing, ticking off the various mission flags you know you've done already. That said, it's not an exact thing since not everything is accounted for, and there may indeed end up being conflicts. Kotekzot's right, though - having to restart and restore an ME2 game is a pain since you have to sit through the opening Normandy destruction before you can do anything to the files.

Comment: @jordie3000 theoretically, you can, but the inevitable differences between a real save and a heavily edited one will likely result in severe to game-breaking bugs.